# How to add another collapsible to right column on Bootstrap Modal Window

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to add another Collapsable right Column on Bootstrap Modal Window. By just clicking on a link. Please check this image.

[image: Check this Image]

Also my fiddle

jsfiddle.net/0q6zwedh/

Comment: Please post valid HTML.

Comment: Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/45kLrxd3/